Implementing GitVersion in Azure Pipelines for GitHub Flow
I am trying to us GitVersion in Azure Pipelines to help with auto-versioning our builds/commits.  My flow is very similar to what is shown in this Feature Branch diagram.  My release branch is called master.
Typical Scenario

master branch is 1.2.0
A change is needed so we create a branch from master. (feature-NewFeature)
We add a new feature & commit to feature branch with +semver:minor
We fix a bug in the new feature & commit to feature with +semver:patch
We push the new branch and commits to the Azure Devops repo.
We test the new branch.
Everything looks good so we create a PR and merge the feature branch into master.

I've run through this scenario a few times as you can see here:

Based on what you can see in the image, I would expect my version to be at 1.4.0 -- (initial tag 1.2 followed by two +semver:feature/minor commits merged into master)
However, you can see from the GitVersion output that everything stays at 1.3.0.  (This was from the final PR -- PR 21285).

I have the following defined for my Azure Pipeline.  (I am not allowed to install GitTools in our environment -- so I've had to manage GitVersion manually.)
name: '1.0.$(Rev:r)'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  projectPath: '**/NugetTestLib/NugetTestLib.csproj'
  projectName: 'NuGet Test Library'
  
pool:
  name: 'Azure Pipelines'

stages:
- stage: Stage 1
  displayName: 'Determine Version Number'
  jobs:
  - job: Versioning
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 0

    - script: 'dotnet tool install --global GitVersion.Tool --version 5.*'
      displayName: 'GitVersion Install'

    - script: 'dotnet-gitversion /config ./GitVersion.yml'
      displayName: 'Print GitVersion variables'

    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Determine version with GitVersion'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $output = dotnet-gitversion /config ./GitVersion.yml | ConvertFrom-Json
          $output.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=GitVersion.$($_.Name)]$($_.Value)"
          }
 
    - script: echo $(GitVersion.SemVer)
      displayName: 'Display New Build Version'

    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Update pipeline build number
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(GitVersion.SemVer)"        

I've tried a number of different gitversion.yaml settings.  Here is what I currently have:
workflow: GitHubFlow/v1
mode: ContinuousDelivery

No matter what I do, the semver never really increments past 1.3.0.  What do I need to do to get major, minor and/or patch to increment properly?
Update
I recently tried updating my gitversion.yaml file to this:
mode: Mainline
branches:
  main:
    regex: ^(master|main)$
    is-mainline: true
    is-source-branch-for: ['feature', 'bugfix']
  feature:
    regex: ^feature?[/-]
    source-branches: ['main']
    tag: feat-{BranchName}
  bugfix:
    regex: ^bugfix?[/-]
    source-branches: ['main']
    tag: bugfix-{BranchName}
ignore:
    sha: []
merge-message-formats: {}

However, I get the same result.
Update 2
I followed the advice below and tried merging with 'Rebase' with the same results.  Notice my branches/commits but no change in my version.
You can see in the results of my build names that the version is not updating.  (You can see that I'm updating the build version with the GitVersion.Semver).



Am I missing something? You're only updating minor once in your description. So it's only incrementing the minor version once.

Yes, a little bit.  Just after the "typical scenario" I state that I've run through it "several times".  If you look at the branch tree, you'll see multiple commits with +semver tags.

On the feature branch, if you have multiple commits that the comments contain the statement "+semver: xxx", and merge all the commits to the master branch at once using a PR, after completing the merge, on the master branch it will generate a new commit that contains the changes from the all the merged commits.
When you trigger a pipeline run from the new commit on master branch, the GitVersion tool will automatically increase the version number only once.


The solution is selecting "Rebase" instead of "Basic merge (no fast-forward)" as the merge type when you merge the new commits from feature branch to master branch. With the "Rebase" merge type, it will copy all the new commits from feature branch to master branch, instead of generating a new commit to combine all the commits.
By this way, when you trigger a new pipeline run on master branch, the GitVersion tool will check all the new commits on master branch and increase the version once for each new commit that contains the statement "+semver: xxx".


The sample of GitVersion.yml file on my side.
# GitVersion.yml

mode: mainline
tag-prefix: '[vV]?'
assembly-informational-format: '{Major}.{Minor}.{Patch}'
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
update-build-number: true

And the sample of pipeline YAML.
# azure-pipelines.yml

steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0

- task: gitversion/setup@1
  displayName: 'Install GitVersion'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.x'
    preferLatestVersion: true

- task: gitversion/execute@1
  displayName: 'Generate Version'

- bash: |
    echo "GitVersion.FullSemVer = $(GitVersion.FullSemVer)"
    echo "GitVersion.SemVer = $(GitVersion.SemVer)"
  displayName: 'View Version'



See my second update -- still not working for me.  Are you using the GitTools plugin?
